# multiple file reader in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I want to specify a path to a folder and want to open all xslt files in said folder one after another.

I tried to do it like this:

```
 QString path = "/misc/example";
 QDir dir(path);
 QStringList filters;
 filters << "*.xslt";

 foreach (QFile file, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files))
 {
      if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
      {
        qDebug("Failed to open file for reading.");
        return 0;
      }
 }
```

but i get this error

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qfile.h:209: Fehler:'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)' is private
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entryList` returns `QStringList` but not some container of `QFiles`. So you should act like this

```
...
foreach ( QString fileName, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files) )
{
    QFile inFile( fileName );
    if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
    {
        qDebug("Failed to open file for reading.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To avoid big overhead with `foreach` and making a list of filenames, I suggest to use [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html)

```
QDirIterator dirIt( path, filters, QDirIterator::Subdirectories );
while ( it.hasNext() )
{
    QFile inFile( it.next() );
    if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
    {
        qDebug("Failed to open file for reading.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest also `const QString& fileName` to avoid possible copying.

Comment: @user2155932 I'll suggest another way in couple of minutes. It would be better, I think

Answer (score 2):

About the error, this line

```
 foreach (QFile file, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files))
```

tries to to copy an object from `dir.entryList` as a `QFile` to `file` while copy-constructor is private. Then, it shows the error.

Try something like this:

```
foreach (QString &name, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files))
{
    QFile file(name);
    if (!file.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```